# Generics Fun: Where typeof(List<T>) != typeof(List<T>), and using Reflection to get a generic method, with generic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, type-equivalence

It was just another day with .NET. Until I had to get generic method of a static class with a generic parameter, using reflection for serialization. Doesn't sound so bad. `GetRuntimeMethod("x", new[] { type })`, as usual should do the trick, or so I thought.

Now, this method keeps returning null for the following variant:
`public static Surrogate<T> BuildSurrogate<T>(List<T> collection)`.

So, a quick copy to LinqPad, and a `GetRuntimeMethods` run later, it seemed to have all the methods as expected. Naturally, I thought perhaps, something wasn't right with the behavior of GetRuntimeMethod, so, I whipped up a quick extension, `GetRuntimeMethodEx` that iterates through, and to my surprise, it failed. What? How could that fail. GetRuntimeMethods has the exact the methodInfo I need.

So, I ended up breaking up the extension into parts to understand what exactly is going on, as in the code below. And it turns out `(cType != cGivenType)` always ended up true.

But a quick inspection, shows they were the same 'apparent' type - `List<T>`. Now being utterly confused, a diff on the dump of the two `typeof(List<T>)`, and it turns out they were not the same!

The `MetadataToken` of the two were exactly the same. However the `RuntimeTypeHandle` were different. The given type had the correct `AssemblyQualifiedName`, and `FullName`, belonging to ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 ```. Great. But oddly enough, the type on the generic method, had both of them as "`null`"!  So, basically, the `List<T>` is a magical type with no corresponding assembly(!?). `It exists, but doesn't`. How fascinating!

Here's a quick dump of the diff between the two, that's relevant.

[image: Image of the differences]

Note the `GenericTypeParameters`, and `IsGenericTypeDefinition` - They are the ones which seem to make perfect sense. The oddities aside, now how could one create a Type that matches this type on the MethodInfo? Potentially, the compiler expects a generic type of `List<>` with the generic parameter `T` - The only problem is, you can't literally make a generic type with `T`. The `T` has to be a type of something, which now invalidates the equality.

```
 private void Main()
    {
        var type = typeof (List<>);
        var m = typeof (Builders).GetRuntimeMethods();
        var surrogateBuilder = typeof (Builders)
                        .GetRuntimeMethodEx("BuildSurrogate", new[] {type});
    }

    static class Builders
    {
        public static Surrogate<T> BuildSurrogate<T>(List<T> collection)
        {
            return new Surrogate<T>
            {
                Items = collection.ToArray(),
            };
        }

        public class Surrogate<T>
        {
            public IEnumerable<T> Items;
        }
    }

    public static class ReflectionExtensions
    {
        public static MethodInfo GetRuntimeMethodEx(
                this Type type, string name, params Type[] types)
        {
            var m = type.GetRuntimeMethods();
            var res = (m.Where(t =>
            {
                var n = name;
                return t.Name.Equals(n);
            }).FirstOrDefault(t =>
            {
                var px = t.GetParameters().ToArray();
                var currentTypes = px.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
                if (currentTypes.Length < 1) return false;
                for (var i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
                {
                    var cGivenType = types[i];
                    for (var j = 0; j < currentTypes.Length; j++)
                    {
                        var cType = currentTypes[j];
                        if (cType != cGivenType) return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }));
            return res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is logical that this fails, never in your code you are binding type parameter T to a type argument using `MakeGenericMethod`

Comment: There is no type you could bind using `MakeGenericMethod` as it's still `List<T>` with unknown `T`.

Comment: @Bas - You cannot bind with an unknown! `Edit:` @Marcin beat me to it. Yup, that's the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I misread. It however cannot work with a `List<>` as the parameter needs to be `List<T>`, which is a different type. You cannot use equality comparison to compare your 'placeholder' `List<>` to `List<T>`. Use the method described in the answer

Comment: Got answer, as described by @Marcin, However, this is confusing, as both types seem to show the (almost) same metadata! The image above demonstrates it. A transparent `GenericTypeDefinition (List<>)` could have solved it cleanly. Anyhow, thanks for the quick resolution. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your type is a `GenericTypeDefinition` (`List<>`) and the one taken from reflecting your class is an actual `List<T>`.

Your code is not readable, so I wrote my own from scratch. The important part is in `TypesMatch` method.

```
public static MethodInfo GetRuntimeMethodEx(
        this Type type, string name, params Type[] types)
{
    var withMatchingParamTypes =
        from m in type.GetRuntimeMethods()
        where m.Name == name
        let parameterTypes = m.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray()
        where parameterTypes.Length == types.Length
        let pairs = parameterTypes.Zip(types, (actual, expected) => new {actual, expected})
        where pairs.All(x => TypesMatch(x.actual, x.expected))
        select m;

    return withMatchingParamTypes.FirstOrDefault();
}

private static bool TypesMatch(Type actual, Type expected)
{
    if (actual == expected)
        return true;

    if (actual.IsGenericType && expected.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        return actual.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == expected;

    return false;
}
```

Returns your method, as expected.

You can't create a `Type` instance that represents `List<T>` with unknown `T`. That's what `GetGenericTypeDefinition` and `List<>` are for.

Comment: Perfect! But quite confusing that `GenericTypeDefinition` is not a transparent and public type. Wish it was, could be lot more logical that way. Sorry about the unreadable code, I did it intently do set breakpoints in between.

PS: Allow me to cancel the effects of the downvoter with my upvote :)